# Writing large Icon to a parcelable in Android

Tags: android, android-memory

I am writing an object into Parcel which has an icon field.

While putting breakpoint in the `writeToParcel` method, I observed that the parcel size before writing the icon is `22456` bytes.

The `Icon` is of type data and here's what `toString` gives in the debugger:
`Icon(typ=DATA len=31189)` which says that the data length is `31189 bytes`, verified this by calling `getDataBytes` inside the class.

However, after this icon is written onto the parcel, the parcel size comes out to be `22572` bytes, which is just `116` bytes more than what it was.

So it seems that something is happening behind the scenes when writing the icon. I couldn't conclude it by looking the source code for [Icon class](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/Icon.java;l=66;bpv=1;bpt=1?q=Icon&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject).

Can someone please explain what's going on here? I've seen some references for ashmen memory in the class but I am not really sure what that means and how it'd add upto this.

Edit: For another object where the preview is `Icon(typ=DATA len=11129)`, the parcel size increases by the same `11129` bytes.

Edit 2:

```
original size: Icon(typ=DATA len=4864) , bytes taken in parcel: 4888
original size: Icon(typ=DATA len=4314) , bytes taken in parcel: 4340
original size: Icon(typ=DATA len=4314) , bytes taken in parcel: 4340
original size: Icon(typ=DATA len=31189) , bytes taken in parcel: 48
original size: Icon(typ=DATA len=11129) , bytes taken in parcel: 11156
original size: Icon(typ=DATA len=58126) , bytes taken in parcel: 48
original size: Icon(typ=DATA len=11705) , bytes taken in parcel: 11732
original size: Icon(typ=DATA len=7713) , bytes taken in parcel: 7740
original size: Icon(typ=DATA len=7713) , bytes taken in parcel: 7740
```

Comment: have you considered the possible "memory alignment" ? You know that parcels are meant to be read by other processes, and reading unaligned memory could produce slower results, so perhaps they're padded? which doesn't explain why `31189` and `58126` occupy only `48` bytes on the other hand.

Comment: Care to show some code, or perhaps a complete [mcve] as well as your Parcel creator class? Perhaps you don't want to send an `Icon` through the parcel, but it's actual `Drawable` or to be more specific - `BitmapDrawable`. their sizes should actually match the bitmap size, or highlight the potential problem in your parcel creator.

Comment: yeah passing bitmap is a different thing. I want to find an answer for the current case where I am passing byte array.

Comment: might i suggest Base64 encoding the byte[] when passing and decoding when receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer to this after digging into the native code.

As we can see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/jb-dev/libs/binder/Parcel.cpp), the in-place blob limit for the parcel is 16KB. If it's larger than that, it is copied into a shared ashmem region.